# How do I enable on click functionality on a material-ui Icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart'
function App(){
     return (
         <div>
             ShoppingCartIcon></ShoppingCartIcon>
         </div>
      )
}
```

I want to open an another page when I click on the icon. How do I do it?

Comment: Do you have the basic routing setup in your project? If yes, all you have to do is create a route for 'shopping-cart' and then link the button to it using the 'Link' tag. Can refer to the documentation here : https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use `Link` from react router to redirect to another route.

```
<Link to="/about"><Icon /></Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to setup a Router in your project. For more information, look into: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start. After you are done seting up your routes, you can navigate through the app in many different ways. One of them would be by using the `useHistory` hook:

```
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart'

function App(){
     const history = useHistory();

     return (
         <div>
             <ShoppingCartIcon onClick={() => history.push("/page")} />
         </div>
      )
}
```

Comment: what is useHistory() here? @FireFighter

Comment: It is a hook provided by reactrouter that gives you access to the history. For more information: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: @NehaChaudhary maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you want to link to an external page or to a route within your website?

Comment: I want to route within the website. @FireFighter

Comment: Then you will need to use react-router to setup the routes, if you havent already done that. There are many ways to route in a single page application. One of them would be my `useHistory` example

Comment: Hi FireFighter, thank you for helping the community. Try adding more information about how you solved the problem, and describe your solution